# Picasso loading images very slowly in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, picasso

I have encountered a problem with Picasso while implementing Chat functionality in an application. The problem that I am facing is that it is loading images very slowly. Images that are returned from the BE could weight up to 500kb. When there is only one image in the thread the loading time is acceptable. When we have got more than one image it becomes a nightmare. On LTE image that weights ~150kb is loading for even 8 seconds. Here is how I use Picasso:

```
Picasso
      .get()
      .load(photoPath)
      .resize(imageSize, imageSize)
      .centerCrop()
      .into(image, object : Callback {
                        override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                            progress.visibility = View.GONE
                        }

                        override fun onSuccess() {
                            progress.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                    })
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? How can I force Picasso to load images faster? For me, it seems that Picasso starts the loading process with some kind of a delay. Maybe important would be that I load elements into RecyclerView and then I scroll it the whole way to the bottom.

EDIT:

For info in a case, someone will have the same problem. I have tried `Glide` fortunately it works better for me. In my opinion, it has smaller `lag` than Picasso. The second thing that helped me a lot was the implementation of an image preview in the notification. This implementation fetches image before I will use it in UI so now all is loaded very fast.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the way you are using Picasso here. Perhaps it is an issue with how you set up your RecyclerView or adapter. Try making a [MCVE] to see if you can reproduce the problem

Comment: You can also try using Glide instead.... or use `RGB_565` instead of `ARGB_888`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I thought about using Glide, but I am pretty sure that Picasso should work properly and without delays

Comment: @EpicPandaForce just for info I have changed lib to Glide as you suggested. I additionally found out that there is a possibility to set priority in Glide, and I have given it a try. Seems to work better, now I stay with Glide